# Only single return value($data) will display codeigniter View page

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a **result.php** page in **view/result.php**

```
<body>        
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>name1</th>
            <th>name2</th>
            <th>name3</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($result as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->name1; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->name2; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->name3; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <?php echo 'Your new value is '.$name1;?>
    <?php echo 'Your new value is '.$name2;?>
    <?php echo 'Your new value is '.$name3;?>
</body>
```

html table is currently working. It retrives data from my table **testing** and display it. The problem is echo part in below code, it doesn't work.

```
<?php echo 'Your new value is '.$name1;?>
<?php echo 'Your new value is '.$name2;?>
<?php echo 'Your new value is '.$name3;?>
```

From the same table testing. It shows an error in the error page it shows `Undefined variable name1,name2,name3`

**controller/example.php**

```
<?php
class Example extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
  {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->helper('form');
   $this->load->helper('url');

 }

 function index() {
  $this->load->view('example_view');
  $this->getvalue();
  $this->edit_content();
 }

 function getvalue()
{
 if ($this->input->post('submit')==true) {
  $data1['name1']=$this->input->post('name1');
  $data1['name2']=$this->input->post('name2');
  $data1['name3']=$this->input->post('name3');
  $this->load->view('result',$data1);

  $this->load->model('Insert_model');
  $this->Insert_model->uploaddata($data);  

 }


}

function edit_content()
    {
        $data   = array();
        $this->load->model('Selected_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $data['result'] = $this->Selected_model->get_contents();
        $this->load->view('result',$data);

}
}
?>
```

Comment: In the error page it shows Undefined variable name1,name2,name3

Comment: you need the assign the value to that variable

Comment: post your controller code ie., assign the value to variable(name1,name2,name3).

Comment: @User786 class Example extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
  {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->helper('form');
   $this->load->helper('url');

 }

 function index() {
  $this->load->view('example_view');
  $this->getvalue();
  $this->edit_content();
 }

Comment: @Userfunction getvalue()
{
 if ($this->input->post('submit')==true) {
  $data1['name1']=$this->input->post('name1');
  $data1['name2']=$this->input->post('name2');
  $data1['name3']=$this->input->post('name3');
  $this->load->view('result',$data1);
   
  $this->load->model('Insert_model');
  $this->Insert_model->uploaddata($data);  
  
 }
 

}

function edit_content()
    {
        $data   = array();
        $this->load->model('Selected_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $data['result'] = $this->Selected_model->get_contents();
  $this->load->view('result',$data);
   
}
}
?>

Comment: @User786 full controller code

Comment: add the code to the question, not as a comment as it's difficult to read/understand and format it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>        
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>name1</th>
        <th>name2</th>
        <th>name3</th>
    </tr>
    <?php if(is_array($result)){ foreach($result as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->name1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->name2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->name3; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; } ?>
</table>
<?php echo 'Your new value is '.$row->name1;?>
<?php echo 'Your new value is '.$row->name2;?>
<?php echo 'Your new value is '.$row->name3;?>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.its working but found new errors in result page.like Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: result
**Filename: views/result.php**

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

**Filename: views/result.php**

Answer (score 0):

If your array is like in the following format.

```
$info = array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name1] => a
            [name2] => b
            [name3] => c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name1] => aa
            [name2] => bb
            [name3] => cc
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name1] => aaa
            [name2] => bbb
            [name3] => ccc
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name1] => aaaa
            [name2] => bbbb
            [name3] => cccc
        )

);
```

Then

```
<body>        
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>name1</th>
        <th>name2</th>
        <th>name3</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach($info as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->name1; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row->name2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->name3; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

The above loop will give you accurate result like.

```
name1    name2    name3
  a        b       c
  aa       bb      cc
  aaa      bbb      ccc
  aaaa     bbbb     cccc
```

Now the following code will generate an error because it does not know the following

```
$row->name1
$row->name1
$row->name1
```

The reason is that these are defined in the scope of foreach loop thats why its generate error.